# Compile a static freeglut library .lib in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries, freeglut

k so this is sort of a silly problem but I'm trying to write a game and I want to use free glut but I can't find a single place to download the .lib and what I could find is a project file that compiles a .dll then after that I don't even know how to implement it into my program can someone please help me out,

- How do I get a freeglut.lib
- How do I use it in VS 2012

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully compile the [freeglut projects](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) that are contained in the download with VS 2012. If you want to learn OpenGL and freeglut then [this place](http://cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/) is a good resource. You can download freeglut, glew and the OpenGl examples and build them with VS 2012, I just did it this week.

Comment: where do you download them tho? and how do you set it so it compiles in .lib not .dll?